# is there a method to identify user actor in different level in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am developing a mobile application to help patients. I hope to use react native for my development. In the mobile application, I need to identify user actors at different levels. If there is a patient or a doctor, All users have to log into the mobile application. I need to identify if one user is logged into the mobile application whether he is a doctor or a patient. I am searching a method for that.

I am expecting an explanation and method for that?

Comment: I am assuming that the users at different levels will have different levels of access to your backend servers/apis. With this in mind, it seems like the user data returned after authentication should supply the user type. Then you can conditionally render the app base on user type

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redux or ContextAPI to save your data in a global state and access it throughout the whole application.

Redux:
https://react-redux.js.org/
ContextAPI:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html